# Display existing roles of each user to column (row to column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Can someone help me how to display the Output below? I can't use the standard joins as the row will not be included if one of the roles does not exist in UserRoles. Just to add, there will be no new roles, only the Admin, Verifier and Approver will be checked. TIA!

Roles table

```
 ID | Role     
 1 | Admin     
 2 | Verifier     
 3 | Approver
```

UserRoles table

```
 UserID | RoleID     
 1 | 1     
 1 | 2     
 2 | 3     
 3 | 2     
 3 | 3
```

Expected Output

```
 UserID | Admin | Verifier | Approver    
 1 | Yes | Yes | No     
 2 | No | No | Yes     
 3 | No | Yes | Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [Role] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [Role])
VALUES
    (1, 'Admin'),
    (2, 'Verifier'),
    (3, 'Approver')
;


CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([UserID] int, [RoleID] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([UserID], [RoleID])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3)

SELECT UserID
    ,max(CASE 
        WHEN ROLE = 'Admin'
            THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END) Admin
    ,max(CASE 
        WHEN ROLE = 'Verifier'
            THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END) Verifier
    ,max(CASE 
        WHEN ROLE = 'Approver'
            THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END) Approver
FROM #Table1 a
JOIN #Table2 B ON a.ID = b.RoleID
GROUP BY UserID
```

output

```
UserID | Admin | Verifier | Approver

1 | Yes | Yes | No

2 | No | No | Yes

3 | No | Yes | Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I haven't thought that I can filter it in CASE WHEN instead of WHERE statement :)